# Load data to BigQuery using the Storage Write API in Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I've been using the very convenient [`load_table_from_dataframe`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-dataframe) function (BigQuery Load Jobs API) to load data which I'm processing using pandas - this has worked for small tables (<10GB) but it is now failing on larger datasets due to the following error:

> 403 Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for Number of partition
> modifications to a column partitioned table. For more information, see
> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas

I understand this is because I'm hitting Google's quota limit on the number of partition modifications which cannot be increased. I've therefore identified the following solutions;

1. Using the BigQuery Storage Write API, which has its own separate quota system.
2. Spreading out your requests over time (jittered truncated exponential backoff and retry)
3. Manually chunking the load into parts that will stay within quota.
4. Utilizing the Python Spark Connector and Dataproc Spark for large batch loads.

I've implemented #2 and #3 which ends up sleeping and not making much progress, and #4 would require substantially more dev time which leaves me with #1.

I can see there is an [example here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api-batch#batch_load_data_using_pending_type), however it's relatively low-level and unclear to me how this translates to loading data from a pandas DataFrame. Could someone please provide a minimal example or pointers to achieve this?

Thank you.

My workflow is: Pull/paginate timeseries data from REST API's > Transform using pandas > Load to BQ

PS: I'm also open to saving processed data as static files locally and uploading manually (via CLI) if this by-passes quota limits.